# Connecting sql developer to oracle 11g from lubuntu to centos

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

*I* *have* Installed **sql-developer** on ***Lubuntu*** and I want to connect **sql-developer** to oracle 11g, oracle 11g installed in another system(**Centos**)and **sql-developer** installed(***Lubuntu***) *while testing the connectivity from **sql-developer** via tns service name its showing* ***error as "Status -Test Failed: IO Error The Network Adapter Couldn't establish the connection"***.  ***TNSPING** is working for service names and ping ip-address is also working in destination sever where we have installed oracle 11g database*.

Please let me know to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Ranjithkumar

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide your TNS-Names File or the configuration of your SQL-Developer? The Error seems to occur because of a false Host-Definition. Be sure that you put in the right SID or Service name. 
If you assume that your configuration must be right, please Check your DNS- and firewall-Settings. Further you can change into the Oracle-Bin Folder and execute the "tnsping" binary with the Host as Parameter.

Comment: I got resolved. we have to configure the service and listener where we installed oracle11g another machine @async